# Time schedule using pg_timetable

Tags: database, postgresql, timetable

I'm currently working with an e-commerse database assignment and I want to use pg_timetable to schedule a fuction like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_condition_after_delay()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE shopping.order_item
    SET condition = 'Pending Pickup'
    WHERE created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 minute'
    AND condition = 'Pending Confirmation';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And this command in postgresql:

```
SELECT timetable.add_job('execute-func', '@every 2 minutes', 'SELECT public.update_condition_after_delay()');
```

Yesterday, it works once when i scheduled it but today, when i start the pg_admin4 again, it does not work but I can't find out why.

I had try to research some documents on pg_timetable and test if my installation is successful.

Comment: `pgAdmin` != `Postgres`, it just a client. The job is set up on the Postgres server, so I am not sure what you expect to see when you start pgAdmin4?

Comment: "it does not work but I can't find out why."    any error messages?

Comment: it just does not work, when i erase all and add_job again, it return success but nothing run after 2 minutes.

Comment: How do you distinguish between it not running and it running but not doing the UPDATE as the conditions are not met?

Comment: In my previous comments I assumed you had `pg_timetable` running. How did you install `pg_timetable`?  Have you started the program?

Comment: yeah, I figure it out that I have to run the program to execute pg_timetable, it does not run underground. Thanks guys